# Doubt about integral with Dirac delta function

Tags: integration

I have an integral like
$$
\int \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta[a^{2} + c\,d\,x + b\,c \,(x - 1)]\,\mathrm d b\,\mathrm d a.
$$
Is it possible to solve the delta for $b$ and extract an expression in terms of $\int \mathrm da$ in the end? $c$, and $d$, will be constants.

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to use a symbol $d$ when you've an integral like $\int dx$.  Sooner of later that habit will cause you problems.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4):

The argument of the Dirac delta is linear in $b$. Therefore, you can redefine the integration variable to absorb the $c(x-1)$ into $b$. Then you have a Dirac delta with a new variable together with a shift. Since you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the shift has no effect; the result would just be 1, but with $1/c(x-1)$ produced by the change of variable. Now $a$ would be gone and therefore the remaining integral would just give you $a$ with an unknown integration constant.

Answer (score -4):

$$\int da\frac{\theta(a^2+cdx+bc(x-1))}{c(x-1)}$$

Comment: How can the result of a definite integral over $b$ still contain $b$?

Comment: I just put it in wolfram integrate, but since it had rando ds and asterisks in it, it was a pain. Could be a typo .. try it yourself

Comment: *try it yourself* I got something that didn’t contain $b$.

Comment: I blame Stephen Wolfram then, since I used _his_ integrator: https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator